# Acceptable overshoot, accuracy, and control bandwidth of a buck converter

Tags: buck, bandwidth, ripple, accuracy, overshoot

I am designing a closed loop buck converter and was wondering what would be the acceptable values/performance for control parameters like accuracy, control bandwidth, and overshoot.

I know that the output capacitor, for example, directly affects the overshoot and the ripple at the output however, one can technically use a very high value capacitance and not see any ripple or overshoot. What is the trade-off here?

Comment: That’s pretty much up to you and your application. What are the requirements of downstream circuits where it’s used?

Comment: Just read the data sheet for the buck controller you plan to use. It'll tell you. If you are totally designing your own (why?) then look at some data sheets for similarly specified OTS devices and form your own opinion as to what will be good or bad.

Comment: Dynamic load changes are handled by the control bandwidth of your design. A large load current step function can be difficult to handle.

Comment: You design a converter for some defined load. Ask your load what kind of supply it needs

Comment: What they said. The parameters that you listed may all be important in a given application. It is the specifiers task to decide which parameters are important and what values they should have. These will vary very widely between applications.

Answer (score 2):

What’s acceptable is entirely application dependent. Full stop. You design a power supply to fulfill a particular need/use, and that’s where such requirements come from.